# What's the windows API for disabling finger input?

Tags: windows, winapi, touch

I need to disable touch input programmatically. So I'm looking for a windows API call which does the same as the option "Use finger as an input device" in the pen/finger control panel.

Any thoughts?

Please note, that the process does not have administrator priviledges.

Comment: Do you want to disable it system-wide, or just for your application?

Comment: Both would be helpful, but I prefer a system-wide (per-user) solution.

Comment: Why are you overriding the user's settings? Won't they be upset that your program changed their preferences? To disable it for your program, you can register as a touch program and then just ignore all the touch events.

Comment: The purpose is to avoid accidential touch input in a certain state on a dedicated system. The user will appreciate it. Registering as a touch program could be worth a try.

Comment: If it's a dedicated system, why not simply design the system without a touch digitizer?  The easiest way to ensure that the user not interact with touch input is to not support touch input.

Comment: Well, because the touch is required in another state.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question was asked 3 years ago... Well, you can set the "TouchGate" value of the registry key "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Wisp\Touch" from "1" to "0" to disable finger Touch.

Doing this does not require administrator privileges.

Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255203/windows-8-touch-toggle).