# Windows 8 Touch Toggle

Tags: touch, windows-8

It is often necessary to disable touch input when using a digitiser pen to avoid 'noise' from e.g. the hand resting on the screen. A programmatic solution exists to disable touch - but maintain pen - input in Windows 7, which changes the TouchGate registry value and broadcasts a system message; it seems that latter part fails in Windows 8.

Does anyone know how to update the code / an alternative solution for Windows 8 (note that my system does not allow me to disable touch input via the control panel GUI).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Touch_Toggle
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser;
           regKey = regKey.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Wisp\Touch", true);
           string currKey = regKey.GetValue("TouchGate").ToString();
           if (currKey == "1")
              regKey.SetValue("TouchGate", 0x00000000);
           else
              regKey.SetValue("TouchGate", 0x00000001);
           regKey.Close();
           User32Utils.Notify_SettingChange();
        }

        internal class User32Utils
        {
            #region USER32 Options
            static IntPtr HWND_BROADCAST = new IntPtr(0xffffL);
            static IntPtr WM_SETTINGCHANGE = new IntPtr(0x1a);
            #endregion

            #region STRUCT
            enum SendMessageTimeoutFlags : uint
            {
                SMTO_NORMAL = 0x0000,
                SMTO_BLOCK = 0x0001,
                SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 0x2,
                SMTO_NOTIMEOUTIFNOTHUNG = 0x0008
            }
            #endregion

            #region Interop

            [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            static extern IntPtr SendMessageTimeout(
                IntPtr hWnd,
                uint Msg,
                UIntPtr wParam,
                UIntPtr lParam,
                SendMessageTimeoutFlags fuFlags,
                uint uTimeout,
                out UIntPtr lpdwResult
            );
            #endregion

            internal static void Notify_SettingChange()
            {
                UIntPtr result;
                SendMessageTimeout(
                    HWND_BROADCAST, 
                    (uint)WM_SETTINGCHANGE,
                    UIntPtr.Zero, 
                    UIntPtr.Zero,
                    SendMessageTimeoutFlags.SMTO_NORMAL, 
                    1, 
                    out result
               );
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After finding no answers elsewhere, an alternative is to toggle the appropriate device (if it is distinct from the pen) using a PowerShell script. Note that I have not tested this solution, since I no longer wish to use Windows 8.

You may need to enable PowerShell script execution on the local machine via group policy (Administrative Templates < Windows Components < Windows PowerShell).

First, download a copy of 'devcon.exe' (from Microsoft) for your machine. The following script then uses this command to achieve the desired effect assuming 'devcon.exe' is in the same directory.

```
$devid = "HID\WACOMVTHID&Col03"

$status = .\devcon status $devid | Select-String "running"

if($status -eq $null) {
  write-host "Enabling touch"
  .\devcon enable $devid
} else {
  write-host "Disabling touch"
  .\devcon disable $devid
}
```

The 'devid' parameter can be found as one of the 'Hardware Ids' in the device's properties.